# Translate numpy to tensor (keras) (loss function)

Tags: numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor, loss-function

I'm trying to define a loss function on the following shape: (NUM_OF_STROKES, STROKE_LEN, 2)
For example, let say NUM_OF_STROKES=1, STROKE_LEN=4, it can be like:
`[[[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4]]]`

I want that my loss function will be the ditances between two corresponding points (sum of all the distances). For example:

```
p1 = [[[a1,b1], [a2,b2], [a3,b3], [a4,b4]]]
p2 = [[[c1,d1], [c2,d2], [c3,d3], [c4,d4]]]
loss = sqrt((a1-c1)^2 + (b1-d1)^2) + ... + sqrt((a4-c4)^2 + (b4-d4)^2)
```

In numpy, I can do:
`np.sum(np.linalg.norm(np.array(p1) - np.array(p2), axis=1))`

But I dont know how to do that in tensrflow
I'm working with tensorflow 2 , keras.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.square(labels - predictions), axis=3)))
```

and `axis = 3` for the batch